# "Class" does not name a type when deriving from template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling with C++ templates. This is simplified version of my code. In real, I have it separated into .cpp and .h files, but I just made it short to show the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class GenericColor
{
};

template<typename T>
class RGB : public GenericColor<T>
{
public:
    HSV toHSV();
};

class HSV : public GenericColor<double>
{
};
```

The compilation result is:

```
prog.cpp:12:2: error: ‘HSV’ does not name a type
  HSV toHSV();
  ^
```

https://ideone.com/HnvC6F

Comment: [When to use forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler reads from top to bottom. You need to forward declare HSV.

put:

```
class HSV;
```

before `class RGB`

Comment: Or move the definition of `HSV` before the definition of `RGB` since there are no dependencies anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler reads the definition of `RGB`, `HSV` is not yet
declared. You need to declare it before. The following code is correct:

```
template<typename T>
class GenericColor
{
};


class HSV : public GenericColor<double>
{
};

template<typename T>
class RGB : public GenericColor<T>
{
public:
    HSV toHSV();
};
```

there are cases where it is not easy to define classes in a suitable
order. In that case, you can just *declare* the one you need, and define it
later. That is named a forward-declaration. See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class GenericColor
{
};

class HSV; // the forward-declaration

template<typename T>
class RGB : public GenericColor<T>
{
public:
    HSV toHSV();
};

// the definition of HSV
class HSV : public GenericColor<double>
{
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `HSV` before you can return it from a member function. In this instance, just cut paste the `HSV` class def above the `RGB` class def.

Comment: Just *declare*, not *define*.